# AngularJS digest cycle and promises

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

In the following I have to call `$scope.$apply()` to kick off a digest cycle and update the view.

```
service.doSomething()
  .then(function(result) {
    $scope.thing = result;
    $scope.$apply(); // <--- Why?
  });
```

Why does `$q` not start a digest cycle when it resolves the promise?

The problem I am having is that if I mock the `doSomething()` method in a unit test and return a resolved promise, I have to call `$scope.$apply()` in the test before checking the result. This naturally results in a `$digest already in progress` error as `$scope.$apply()` is called twice in succession.

Comment: you should not have to do this. can you give more context?

Comment: Actually, while I was grabbing you a more concrete example I realised I am returning a Parse JS SDK promise from that service method and not a $q promise. I will switch it to $q and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Okay that does work. Silly me! No more broken promises.

Comment: nice. glad you worked it out. :-)